# Java Step Counter Issue

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a step counter for one of my LAB assignments.

> A pedometer treats walking 1 step as walking 2.5 feet. Define a method named feetToSteps that takes a double as a parameter, representing the number of feet walked, and returns an integer that represents the number of steps walked. Then, write a main program that reads the number of feet walked as an input, calls method feetToSteps() with the input as an argument, and outputs the number of steps.
>
> Use floating-point arithmetic to perform the conversion.
>
> Ex: If the input is:
>
> ```
> 150.5
> ```
>
> the output is:
>
> ```
> 60
> ```

The code I have written is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static double feetToSteps(int userFeet) {
        return userFeet / 2.5;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(feetToSteps(in.nextInt()));
    }
}
```

But the output I get with input of 150.5 is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:11)
```

It looks like my input is not matching what it is expecting. I am assuming I need it to recognize the input can be a float, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right line of thinking. Any suggestions?

Comment: The input `150.5` is NOT an integer.  So why are you reading it as an integer?  The instructions say "read a `double` and convert it to an `int`".

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* - 1) Read your instructions / requirements carefully and understand them before you start coding.  2) Use the javadocs to understand the APIs you need to call.  In this case the javadoc for `Scanner` will list all of its methods, and the methods you need to use will be obvious.  You can find the javadocs using Google; e.g. by googling "javadoc Scanner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `in.nextInt()`, so it is expecting the input in the console to be an integer. However, you are entering `150.5`, which is a double. So, you should use `nextDouble` instead of `nextInt`.

You will also need to change the type of the parameter `userFeet` in `feetToSteps` from `int` to `double`, and change the return type from `double` to `int`, and cast the return value.

The full fixed code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {
   
   public static int feetToSteps(double userFeet) {
        return (int) (userFeet / 2.5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print(feetToSteps(in.nextDouble()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

public static int feetToSteps(double userFeet) {

```
    return (int) (userFeet / 2.5);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(feetToSteps(in.nextDouble()));
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).